# Upgrade cluster on Google Container Engine

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to upgrade my cluster to use the newest version of Kubernetes. I see Google Container Engine has the following tool:

https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/clusters/upgrade?hl=en

However, after I upgrade my cluster and everything finishes successfully, when I see my cluster on the web console I still see the old version (1.9.3). When you create a new cluster version is 1.0.1, so I expect my cluster to upgrade to that version. I also tried upgrading to 0.21.4 with the same results.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web console may be reporting your *initial* cluster version rather than the current version of you master and nodes. If you want to see all of the versions for your cluster, try running

`gcloud beta container clusters  --zone=<zone> describe <cluster-name> | grep -i version`

and it should print out something like

```
currentMasterVersion: 0.21.4
currentNodeVersion: 0.19.3
initialClusterVersion: 0.19.3
```

If your initial cluster version was 0.19.3 then your master won't have been upgraded to 1.0.x yet (but you should have received a notice that you will be upgraded soon).

Once your master has been upgraded, you can follow the instructions at the link you found to upgrade your nodes to the same version as your master.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like that's the case. I wanted to know if I could upgrade my cluster before. I ended up deleting and creating a new cluster.

Comment: Any clusters that were created after the beta announcement (starting around version 0.19.1) will be getting upgraded to 1.0.

Comment: Ah, OK. These clusters where on version 0.18.2. Didn't have a lot of things so was easy to do the migration. Thanks.